# Can a line integral in R3 be seen as a special case of a multiple integral in R3?

Tags: integration

Can a line integral be seen as a special case of a multiple integral in R3?

I guess not, as this is akin to asking if a simple integral can be evaluated over a point. However since both types of integrals deal with objects (curves or volumes) in 3D and their integrand is a function of points in R3 there has to be a link right?

Comment: Isn't a line integral always evaluated over a curve? The domain of integration isn't $\mathbb R^3$, it's a curve $\gamma$ (which can then be pulled back to an interval  $I\subseteq \mathbb R$ as $\gamma:I\to\mathbb R^3$).

Comment: But the curve lives in R3 (in my case). Maybe domain of integration isn't the right word? I know what you mean but saying the domain is a curve is saying the domain is an object in R3.

Comment: The curve is parameterized by a real parameter. The image could lie in $\mathbb R^{275}$, it makes no difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> both types of integrals have their domain of integration over R3

Given some function $f:\Bbb R^3\to X$ (where exactly what $X$ is is irrelevant, as long as it makes sense to integrate) and a path $\gamma:[a,b]\to\Bbb R^3$, then the integral of $f$ along $\gamma$ is really the integral
$$
\int_a^bf(\gamma(t))\,dt
$$
which is an integral over $[a,b]\subseteq \Bbb R$. It just so happens that some intermediate step in the calculation uses $\Bbb R^3$.

Also, calculating multiple integrals became much easier to me once I stopped thinking of them as something inherently multidimensional. A triple integral is really a one-dimensional integral where what we integrate is itself a one-dimensional integral where the integrand is an integral.

So really, in my mind, they are both one-dimensional.

Comment: That's also how I think about them actually, but say we do think visually for a moment and you imagine a multiple integral in R3 squeezing till the region has become a line (or surface for the link with a surface integral). There has to be some sort of link right? (And also, altough irrelevant to the point you're trying to get across, in the general case there is the derivative of the parametrisation in the formula)